# Is there any texteditor that I can also insert images in the middle of texts in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, editor

I would like to make a blog app by flutter in which people will write posts with text and picture.

I learned how to make the form that image and text are separated like in Instagram.

But what I'm trying to make is that people can insert image files in a text editor.

I'm wondering if there is any library that support this function.

Comment: i think this link will be helpful..https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr

Comment: You can check this package also https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_summernote

Comment: Or this one https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor